# Problem with showing data in Accordian using an XML file and VBox container

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

I am using an XML file to populate my Accordian. But I am missing something which is not showing the labels of VBox in the Accordian. I am trying to get the labels from my XML file i.e 'name' of each user should appear on each Vbox in the Accordian.

Can you spot any logical error in following code:

**XML file: currentUsers.xml**

```
 <currentUsers>     
               <user>   
                  <name>Tom</name>  
                  <age>34</age>
               </user>
               <user>   
                  <name>Jerry</name>    
                  <age>99</age>
              </user>
 </currentUsers>
```

**MXML file:**

```
 <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
                import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable] private var userArray : ArrayCollection;

            private function serviceHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
                userArray = event.result.currentUsers.user;
            }   

            private function send_data():void{ 
                    service.send(); 
            } 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
        <mx:HTTPService id="service" url="currentUsers.xml" result="serviceHandler(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

<mx:Accordion includeIn="UserList" x="10" y="10" width="554" height="242">
        <mx:Repeater id="rep" dataProvider="{userArray}">
            <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%"
                     verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center"
                     label="{rep.currentItem.user}"  >
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Found the problem.

Label of VBox should have been set to currentItem.name, instead of currentItem.user.

```
<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%"
                     verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center"
                     label="{rep.currentItem.name}"  >
</mx:VBox>
```

Thank you all.